# XGboost gives me 100% prediction accuracy, for my binary classification problem. How can I solve it?

Tags: r, classification, xgboost

XGBoost gives me 100% prediction accuracy, for a binary classification problem. This seems too good to be true. How can i solve it?

I am using a normalized dataset (max-min or z-score), already split it as training and validation set, and I am using training set values in order to predict the validation set. In both subsets, data is very alike obviously, but there is nothing i can do about it. I also avoid look-forward bias. What else can be the possible reason for 100% accuracy and how can i solve it? Thank you very much!

My code is:

```
train_x=data.matrix(tmp[,-40])
train_y=tmp[,40]
test_x=data.matrix(tmp2[,-40])
test_y=tmp2[,40]
test_y=as.factor(test_y)

xgb_train = xgb.DMatrix(data=train_x, label=train_y)
xgb_test = xgb.DMatrix(data=test_x, label=test_y)


set.seed(12345)
xgbc=xgboost(data=xgb_train, max.depth=4, nrounds=200)
print(xgbc)

preds=predict(xgbc,test_x)
preds[preds>0.5] = "1"
pred_y = as.factor(test_y)
print(pred_y)

cm = confusionMatrix(test_y, pred_y)
print(cm)
```

Code output is:

```
> xgbc=xgboost(data=xgb_train,max.depth=4, nrounds=200, nthread=2, eta=1, 
objective="binary:logistic")
[1] train-error:0.415888 
[2] train-error:0.390654 
[3] train-error:0.368692 
[4] train-error:0.323832 
[5] train-error:0.307944 
[6] train-error:0.278037 
[7] train-error:0.259346 
[8] train-error:0.240187 
[9] train-error:0.232710 
[10]    train-error:0.224766 
[11]    train-error:0.208879 
[12]    train-error:0.192523 
[13]    train-error:0.185981 
[14]    train-error:0.177103 
[15]    train-error:0.168224 
[16]    train-error:0.157944 
[17]    train-error:0.141121 
[18]    train-error:0.132243 
[19]    train-error:0.132243 
[20]    train-error:0.121495 
[21]    train-error:0.109346 
[22]    train-error:0.101869 
[23]    train-error:0.100000 
[24]    train-error:0.090654 
[25]    train-error:0.080374 
[26]    train-error:0.078505 
[27]    train-error:0.069626 
[28]    train-error:0.063084 
[29]    train-error:0.066822 
[30]    train-error:0.056542 
[31]    train-error:0.044860 
[32]    train-error:0.042991 
[33]    train-error:0.039252 
[34]    train-error:0.037383 
[35]    train-error:0.029439 
[36]    train-error:0.023832 
[37]    train-error:0.018692 
[38]    train-error:0.011682 
[39]    train-error:0.011215 
[40]    train-error:0.010748 
[41]    train-error:0.009346 
[42]    train-error:0.007477 
[43]    train-error:0.005140 
[44]    train-error:0.005140 
[45]    train-error:0.006075 
[46]    train-error:0.003271 
[47]    train-error:0.002804 
[48]    train-error:0.003271 
[49]    train-error:0.002804 
[50]    train-error:0.002804 
[51]    train-error:0.002336 
[52]    train-error:0.002336 
[53]    train-error:0.002336 
[54]    train-error:0.002336 
[55]    train-error:0.000935 
[56]    train-error:0.000467 
[57]    train-error:0.000000 
[58]    train-error:0.000000 
[59]    train-error:0.000000 
[60]    train-error:0.000935 
[61]    train-error:0.000467 
[62]    train-error:0.000000 
[63]    train-error:0.000000 
[64]    train-error:0.000000 
[65]    train-error:0.000000 
[66]    train-error:0.000000 
[67]    train-error:0.000000 
[68]    train-error:0.000000 
[69]    train-error:0.000000 
[70]    train-error:0.000000 
[71]    train-error:0.000000 
[72]    train-error:0.000000 
[73]    train-error:0.000000 
[74]    train-error:0.000000 
[75]    train-error:0.000000 
[76]    train-error:0.000000 
[77]    train-error:0.000000 
[78]    train-error:0.000000 
[79]    train-error:0.000000 
[80]    train-error:0.000000 
[81]    train-error:0.000000 
[82]    train-error:0.000000 
[83]    train-error:0.000000 
[84]    train-error:0.000000 
[85]    train-error:0.000000 
[86]    train-error:0.000000 
[87]    train-error:0.000000 
[88]    train-error:0.000000 
[89]    train-error:0.000000 
[90]    train-error:0.000000 
[91]    train-error:0.000000 
[92]    train-error:0.000000 
[93]    train-error:0.000000 
[94]    train-error:0.000000  
[95]    train-error:0.000000 
[96]    train-error:0.000000 
[97]    train-error:0.000000 
[98]    train-error:0.000000 
[99]    train-error:0.000000 
[100]   train-error:0.000000    

> print(xgbc)
##### xgb.Booster
raw: 186.6 Kb 
call:
xgb.train(params = params, data = dtrain, nrounds = nrounds, 
watchlist = watchlist, verbose = verbose, print_every_n = print_every_n, 
early_stopping_rounds = early_stopping_rounds, maximize = maximize, 
save_period = save_period, save_name = save_name, xgb_model = xgb_model, 
callbacks = callbacks, max.depth = 4, nthread = 2, eta = 1, 
objective = "binary:logistic")
params (as set within xgb.train):
max_depth = "4", nthread = "2", eta = "1", objective = "binary:logistic", 
silent = "1"
xgb.attributes:
niter
callbacks:
cb.print.evaluation(period = print_every_n)
cb.evaluation.log() 
# of features: 38 
niter: 200
nfeatures : 38 
evaluation_log:
iter train_error
   1    0.415888
   2    0.390654
---                 
 199    0.000000
 200    0.000000

preds=predict(xgbc,test_x)
> preds
[1] 7.273692e-01 1.643806e-02 3.032141e-04 9.764441e-01 9.691942e-02 
5.343258e-01 9.090783e-01
[8] 5.609832e-01 4.061035e-01 1.105066e-01 4.406907e-03 9.946358e-01 
7.929156e-01 4.119191e-03
[15] 3.098451e-01 2.945659e-04 3.966548e-03 7.829595e-01 1.698021e-01 
9.574184e-01 7.132806e-01
[22] 1.044374e-01 9.024003e-01 5.769060e-01 5.096554e-02 1.751429e-01 
9.982671e-01 9.993696e-01
[29] 6.521277e-01 5.780852e-03 4.867651e-01 9.707865e-01 8.398834e-01 
1.825542e-01 1.134274e-01
[36] 7.154977e-02 5.450470e-01 1.047506e-01 3.099218e-03 2.268739e-01 
9.023346e-01 8.026977e-01
[43] 3.844074e-01 4.463347e-01 8.543612e-01 9.998935e-01 8.699111e-01 
6.243381e-02 1.137973e-01
[50] 9.385086e-01 9.994442e-01 8.376440e-01 8.492180e-01 3.362629e-04 
4.316351e-02 9.234415e-01
[57] 8.924388e-01 9.977444e-01 6.618840e-02 2.186051e-04 1.647688e-03 
8.050095e-03 6.535615e-01
[64] 4.707330e-01 9.138927e-01 5.177013e-02 3.349773e-04 9.392425e-01 
4.979803e-02 2.934091e-01
[71] 8.948106e-01 9.854530e-01 9.795361e-02 9.275551e-01 5.865968e-01 
9.746857e-01 3.859183e-01
[78] 1.194406e-01 3.267710e-01 6.294726e-01 9.250816e-01 6.118813e-02 
3.394562e-01 7.257250e-04
[85] 8.491386e-01 7.081388e-03 3.268852e-01 8.931246e-01 2.204458e-01 
8.818560e-01 9.923303e-01
[92] 9.845840e-01 7.688413e-01 9.803721e-01 9.958567e-01 9.500723e-01 
7.733757e-01 9.368727e-01
[99] 3.276393e-01 9.952766e-01 2.130413e-01 8.992375e-02 8.594028e-02 
8.160641e-01 9.915828e-01

> preds[preds>0.5] = "1"
> preds[preds<=0.5]= "0"
> pred_y = as.factor(test_y)
> print(pred_y)
[1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
[51] 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1

> test_y=as.factor(test_y)
> cm = confusionMatrix(test_y, pred_y)
> print(cm)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

      Reference
```

Prediction   0   1
         0 421   0
         1   0 497

```
           Accuracy : 1         
             95% CI : (0.996, 1)
No Information Rate : 0.5414    
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16 

              Kappa : 1
```

Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA

```
        Sensitivity : 1.0000    
        Specificity : 1.0000    
     Pos Pred Value : 1.0000    
     Neg Pred Value : 1.0000    
         Prevalence : 0.4586    
     Detection Rate : 0.4586
```

Detection Prevalence : 0.4586
      Balanced Accuracy : 1.0000

```
   'Positive' Class : 0
```

Comment: Can you paste the output from xgboost iterations, both for train and test set.

Comment: Impossible to solve without the code, unfortunately. Most likely you accidentally compare true classes with true classes instead of predicted classes.

Comment: I just added the code, I hope it helps. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post the output of the model building process, all the iterations (all the measures). Also, have you checked that `tmp` and `tmp2` are different?

Comment: I have just added the outputs. Prediction 0 1 0 421 0 1 0 497 states the confusion matrix, in which i have 100% accuracy. I have also eyeballed that tmp and tmp2 are different, tmp is the training set and tmp2 is the validation. However, how can i be sure that they are statistically different from each other? Apart from that, what can be the problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: train error can indeed go to 0. you have overfitted everything. What about validation error though? As for the predictions, you have probably mixed it and added training Y in the place of validation Y.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're seriously overfitting to your training data, and you should use cross validation instead of just a naive train-test split. There are a number of ways to do this. You can do it with `xgb.cv` inside of the `xgboost` package in R, for one. I prefer `Tidymodels`, but that's a different rabbit hole. My guess is that if you tune a parameter like `gamma`, you'll end up with non-zero loss because the `gamma > 0` will help prevent overfitting by pruning your trees. You can also help prevent overfitting by growing fewer, shallower trees, subsampling features, etc. All of these options can be tuned with `xgb.cv`

Answer (score -2):

Try checking the correlation of the predictor variables with the output. Try removing variables with high correlation because it introduces high bias. This solved my issue with 100% accuracy.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer